# Summarizing max and min dates for each unique element of a column

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a very large dataframe which looks as following:

```
Col1 StartDate  EndDate
A    4/5/2021   4/5/2021
A    4/6/2021   4/6/2021
A    4/11/2021  4/11/2021
B    10/25/2020 10/25/2020
B    10/26/2020 10/27/2020
```

I need to get the following:

```
Col1 StartDate  EndDate
A    4/5/2021   4/6/2021
A    4/11/2021  4/11/2021
B    10/25/2020 10/27/2020
```

Where for each unique element of `Col1`, I get the maximum consecutive days and take the max and min of those consecutive days to create a new `StartDate` and `EndDate` columns.

I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Does each `StartDate` -`EndDate` in a single row only span 1 day maximum? Basically, what tells you that two periods are consecutive? Only the `StartDate` column or do you need to consider `EndDate` as well?

Comment: No, please look at the last row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) [`dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) of `StartDate`, [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) as your groupby key to get contiguous groups of consecutive days:

```
# If required - cast StartDate & EndaDate to datetime dtype
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])

(df.groupby(df['StartDate'].diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum())
 .agg({'Col1':'first','StartDate':'min', 'EndDate':'max'}))
```

[out]

```
          Col1  StartDate    EndDate
StartDate                           
1            A 2021-04-05 2021-04-06
2            A 2021-04-11 2021-04-11
3            B 2020-10-25 2020-10-27
```

#### Explanation

`df['StartDate'].diff().dt.days` returns the difference (timedelta in the case of dates) from the previous row in days:

```
0      NaN
1      1.0
2      5.0
3   -168.0
4      1.0
Name: StartDate, dtype: float64
```

`.ne(1)` is just a boolean - "not equal" to `1`:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: StartDate, dtype: bool
```

and finally, `.cumsum()` is the cumulative sum of this boolean `Series`, with each "group" being made up of consecutive days:

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
Name: StartDate, dtype: int32
```

---

#### Update

Running with last row removed:
[image]

Comment: I think this is close to what the OP is looking for but I think using `.ne(1)` is not correct because if the start and end date are the same and there is only one record for that group it will not be returned. For example, run your code with the last row removed: `df = df.iloc[:3, :]`

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue with running it with last row removed? What is the expected output for that case?

Comment: I think there will be a problem with your solution if "B" had similar dates as in any of A or if the column 1 is not sorted? Shouldn't you group on Col1 first and then evaluate the date groups?

Comment: Running it with the last row removed will not return a start and end date for `B` when, based on the question, I believe  `B,10/25/2020,10/25/2020` should be returned.

Comment: @ChrisA, you are correct, I used `.iloc[:3]` and not 4

Comment: @Zanam if you groupby `Col1`, you will only have 2 groups, `['A', 'B']`, it won't pick up your required 2nd 'A' group with consecutive dates

Comment: @chris_a your works but it needs Col1 and StartDate to be sorted else the diff() function doesn't pick up. Thanks. Upvote

Comment: You could try grouping on `Col1` as well as the conseuctive groups..? `(df.groupby(['Col1', df['StartDate'].diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()], as_index=False).agg({'StartDate':'min', 'EndDate':'max'}))`